# how to send parameter in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have one AJAX call. I need to pass some parameters to my function. This is my AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'lib/function.php',
    data: {
        action: 'getStoreSupplyItems', 
        id: store_id, 
        indent: 1
    },
    success: function(output) {
        //alert(output);
        $('#response').html(output);
    }
});
```

Here is my back end function definition that I am trying to call:

```
function getStoreSupplyItems($category = '')
{
    global $db;
    $data = $_REQUEST;
    $category = (!empty($category) ? ' AND cim.item_group_code IN ("'.$category.'") ' : '');

    if ($data['id'] != "") 
    {
        $store = $data['id'];
    } 
    else
    {
        $store = $_SESSION['user']['store']['id'];  
    }
```

How can I pass some arguments to the function? The parameter that I want to pass is something like '12,5,6'.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you need?

Comment: Just add another property to the object you provide to `data`...?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan : That is one solution. But If do so I need to change the condition of $category in backend. It will affect some other functionalities.

Comment: What I need is php I need to get '2,12,5' this string in $category field.

Comment: Do you use some Framework? E.g. in Yii you can pass parameter via GET and it will be feeded to action function

Comment: No I am not using any frameworks.

Comment: There is something missing here in your example. I don't think we have all the info we need. Where is the code in PHP that looks at the request variables and then decides what function to call? You've shown us the ajax request, and a PHP function, but nothing in between.  i.e. How does the getStoreSupplyItems function get called?

Comment: @django '2,12,5' is one string or 3 different params you wish to pass to `getStoreSupplyItems` function?

Comment: one string it is. Becourse I am expecting one argument in the definition.

Comment: You make ajax call to lib/functions.php which receives 3 params: action, id, indent. Please look at the file, see how it call the function you specify in action params. By knowing how it works, you can send the parameter easily. If you share lib/functions.php maybe we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `switch` statement in your php file and then call the function passing the arguments. Like this

```
switch($_REQUEST["action"]){
  case "getStoreSupplyItems" :
    getStoreSupplyItems("2,12,5");
    break;
}
```

In your `getStoreSupplyItems` function you can get the value as a param and also use other `get` params by `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET`.

I hope this is what you looking for.

Comment: This is really nice one. It is useful and Can I ask one more question Like What if the parameter is changing.

Comment: How will it change? Are you sending that param in your ajax request?

Comment: Yes ,I need to send it from the ajax request. for different events I need to send different params.

Comment: Then you can simply do this `getStoreSupplyItems($_REQUEST["param_which_contains_the_vaue"]);`

Answer (score 1):

To pass your data you have to make a call like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "lib/function.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
 }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 });
```

then, in your PHP function you have to access to params via $_POST['name'] and $_POST['location']